# Joining two tables and inserting a year column using SQL

Tags: sql, ssms

I am using SSMS. I need to combine two tables in SQL.They contain the same columns but are datasets from two different years. Neither contains a column with dates. How can I combine both tables and differentiate them by year by adding a year column (2018 and 2019)?

Answer (score 3):

Use can use `union all`:

```
select t.*, 2018 as yyyy
from t_2018 t
union all
select t.*, 2019 as yyyy
from t_2019;
```

Comment: I got an error msg- All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @snoosan . . . Your question explicitly says "They contain the same columns".  This seems not to be true.  You should list out the columns that you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case of two tables different number of column you have to specify column name explicitly , as for `union all` operation number of column must be same in both selection and remember their data types also need to be same

```
select t.col1,t.col2, 2018 as y
from t_2018 t
union all
select t1.col1,t1.col2, 2019 as y
from t_2019 t1;
```